# Wso2 API Manager STATS_DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I'm having a hard time understanding what is STATS_DB used for.
I have a distributed deployment of API Manager and Analytics, should I create the STATS_DB? If yes, should it be shared between API Manager and Analytics? Is there any script to launch in the db itself?

Thanks for the clarifications

Answer (score 0):

It's DB for Analytics.

[Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Installing+and+Configuring+the+Databases) is written:
*Table creation of the statistics database is handled by the Analytics scripts when you configure APIM Analytics, so you will create the statistics database in this step but will not specify a source script.*

You may need to create only additional colum as stated [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#ConfiguringAPIMAnalytics-Step4-Configurethedatabases), find "*Create the AM_USAGE_UPLOADED_FILES table in the APIM_ANALYTICS_DB database.*"

Comment: Hi, there is no STATS_DB mentioned in the link you sent. Moreover a STATS_DB is not even mentioned during the APIM Analytics configurations. In the second link the db is APIM_ANALYTICS_DB and not STATS_DB...can you please be more precise? In the Analytics yaml i find no evidence of the STATS_DB. thank you @Valdis Liepiņš

Comment: Hi,
This messed my head for a while in the beginning.
I just ignored STATS_DB and assumed It's Analytics DB and seems that's it. I think this is the [link](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/4985) case.

Comment: Regarding sharing APIM and Analytic, see my communication with wso:

_If I'm deploying all APIM components on separate servers, do I need to configure file_<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml_ _and note datasource WSO2AM_STATS_DB on non-analytic nodes?_
`No, since you are using WSO2AM Analytics 2.6.0 there is no need to share the data sources.`

Comment: thank you, this messed my head too :(. In fact I created the APIM_ANALYTICS_DB database for the AM Analytics and did not share such db with API manager, I think the store & publisher just pull the data via REST API exposed by APIM Analytics 2.6.0, am I correct? Moreover, just worker profile needed to be ran in the AM Analytics

Comment: Yes, only worker profile needs to be run. Essentially STATS_DB and APIM_ANALYTICS_DB are same, it seems that the documentation refers to the DB with different names. From APIM 2.6.0 onwards, analytics DB need not be shared with APIM